# Getting credit card type not allowed error in Paytrace using protect.js

Tags: payment-gateway, credit-card

I followed Client-Side Encryption steps using protect.js in Paytrace API Documentation. When enter test credit card which given by paytrace website, i am getting error message:

description: "credit card type not allowed"
responseCode: "400"

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Check your token.
In my case I was passing token as query string so I had to encode and decode.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).